# An absolute position element jump off when the sticky header active

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a sticky nav header. Follow the header is a main image and a table is on the image with absolute position. The sticky nav header is working well but the table jump off the image when I scroll the window.

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/sarashi/y8td1s15/

HTML

```
<header>
  <div id="main-nav">Main-Nav</div>
  <div id="main-img">Main-Image</div>
  <div id="table">
     A Table Here
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</section>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var menu = document.querySelector('#main-nav');
var origOffsetY = menu.offsetTop;

        function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >0) {
            $('#main-nav').addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            $('#main-nav').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    }

document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

CSS

```
#main-nav { 
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ee3e64;
  z-index:9999;
}

#main-img {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:#A57BF6;
}

#table{
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  width:80px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  right:0;
  background:#0FB2F4;
}

.sticky{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the element `#main-nav` becomes sticky/fixed, it is removed from the normal document flow. This means that the `#main-img` element doesn't take it to account, and it is moved underneath.

One simple work-around would be to displace the `#main-nav` element when it is sticky. You don't need to change your HTML.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/a22o0sqb/)

```
#main-nav.sticky ~ #main-img {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

The selector `#main-nav.sticky ~ #main-img` will select the succeeding `#main-img` sibling element when the `#main-nav` element has the class `.sticky`.

Comment: Thanks the detail answer. One simple line css make the scrolling more smooth.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is **NOT** Required.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8td1s15/2/

Just make few changes to the CSS (and get a Smooth Scrolling too).

Add **position: fixed**

```
#main-nav { 
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ee3e64;
  z-index:9999;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Add **padding-top: 50px;**

```
.inner-wrapper
{
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#table{
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  width:80px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background:#0FB2F4;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is easier for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `#main-img` and `#table` by an element(`div#inner-wrapper`).

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/y8td1s15/1/)

Comment: This doesn't completely solve the issue. It doesn't scroll down smoothly. Try scrolling down 5px and you will notice that the element bounces away. Compare your example to mine..

Comment: Such an easy way to solve the problem that I didn't think of. Thanks a lot. Also thanks Josh Crozier here.